# PostgreSQL в командной строке

Tags: postgresql, командная-строка, psql

Сегодня, я столкнулся с такой проблемой у меня в командной строке на Windows 10 Pro я подключаюсь к базе данных через psql и к примеру пишу \? чтобы узнать больше информации о том как использовать postgresql в командной строке, и в ответ я получаю кашу из символов и букв как это решить?

Версия PostgreSQL 15.1
[image: Скрин с проблемой]

Comment: Такого предупреждения не было ? ` WARNING: Console code page (866) differs from Windows code page (1251)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.`

Comment: У меня так не воспроизводится, попробовать не могу, если есть желание попробуйте в PowerShell такая же ситуация?

Comment: Используй gitbash или powershell

Comment: Стоп, эта ошибка только что появилась я просто закрыл командною и открыл подключился снова и эта ошибка.

Comment: Короче, я уже решил эту проблему просто надо выбрать кодовою страницу на русском команда:  cmd.exe /c chcp 1251